# Difference between composite entity and attributed relationship

Tags: database-design, entity-relationship, data-modeling

I am going through and solidifying my knowledge of the entity relationship modeling terminology. My question is what is the difference between a **composite entity** and an **attributed relationship**? To me they seem like they are one and the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice the difference depends on what the data modeller intends to convey in the model and how it is to be interpreted and used.

In a relational model implementation (or in SQL) they are the same thing because both entities and relationships are represented as tables (relations). In other data models where relationships are represented with distinct data structures of their own there may be a difference.